# Using the equivalent of 'not exists' within drools accumulate

Tags: java, drools, exists, accumulate

My question is about using the equivalent of the 'not exists' construct within a Drools accumulate function.

I make use of a simple accumulation of Performance objects with the following rule part which compiles fine and produces expected results:

```
rule "rule-conflicting-code-set-1" 
...
when
...
    $conflicts : List(size() > 1) 
            from accumulate( 
                $p : Performance(code == "FOO", /*other conditions*/)  
                from $patient.performances,
                collectList($p)) 

then
...
end
```

Now I would like to extend the rule with an extra condition. I want to prevent Performances that satisfy a certain condition from being accumulated (ie, ending up in the $conflicts list).

The new condition is: I do not want to accumulate a **Performance** for which there exists an **Attention** that contains that performance. **Attention** is an object with a **performanceSet** field that holds objects of type **Performance** (Set performanceSet;). I created **thisPerformance()** as a method of **Performance** as a way to refer to **$p**.

The condition itself would look like this:

```
not exists Attention(performanceSet contains thisPerformance())
```

I tried to rewrite the corresponding accumulate like this:

```
$conflicts : List(size() > 1) 
        from accumulate( 
            $p : Performance(
                       code == "FOO", 
                       not exists Attention(performanceSet contains 
                           thisPerformance()),
                       /*other conditions*/)  
            from $patient.performances,
            collectList($p))
```

The compiler complains about the 'exists' keyword: *[ERR 102] Line 50:40 mismatched input 'exists' in rule "rule-conflicting-code-set-1". Parser returned a null Package.*

I suspect that the solution to my problem will look quite different, but let the example serve as an explanation of what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not exists` is not a valid construct in Drools. Simply use `not` instead.

Then, what you are looking for is to use multiple patterns in the accumulate. You need to rewrite your rule to something like this:

```
$conflicts : List(size() > 1) 
    from accumulate( 
        ($p : Performance(code == "FOO") from $patient.performances and
        not Attention(performanceSet contains $p)),
        collectList($p))
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: That was exactly the syntax I was looking for! Thank you so much!